# Check if group input node was passed a value, optional default value

Tags: node-editor, groups

I am trying to creat a green screen filter. I would like to have the option of passing it a background image, but if no image was passed, then to just make the background transparent. How would I go about checking if a background image was passed to the input?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default an image texture with no associated file will output a completely black value. You can use this to drive the alpha value of your background, using a "Math" node set to "Greater Than 0" in order to have full transparency when there is no image texture and zero transparency when there is an associated image texture.

Comment: if the background image has black in it though, then it will end up transparent though wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes indeed ! You could however tweak your background image to be not completely black, having a color like (R(001),G(000),B(000)) It will still appear as black but your node network will consider the value is in fact greater than 0

Answer (score 0):

An image is interpreted as having colors made out of 4 RGBA components in range 0..1. For example, if an image has 32 bit colors, each component is an 8 bit integer in range 0..255, so it's interpreted as x/255 to be converted to the 0..1 range.

(aditionally, if *Color Space* is not set as *non-color*, Blender also applies a curve to reshape the distribution of colors so it resembles physical value of the strength of light, called *linear* color space, but this is irrelevant to this problem as the color components still stay in 0..1 range, hence the parentheses)

That color is then processed as a vector of 3 components RGB (which in the node tree is displayed as a yellow *Color* type, but it's the same thing as a blue *Vector* type), and separately Alpha value. Each of those 4 values is stored in [float32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). Such type is not limited to 0..1 range! It seems so, because sliders are soft-locked to that range - however, you can manually input a value outside of that range...

(in shaders, color components often go outside 0..1 range, either by accident when you do some operations or them, or intentionally, for example in the *Filmic* color transform, the actual value of the full white color is around `16.19`; again, parentheses)

So it seems the best [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) to pick is not black as Gorgious suggested, but one outside the 0..1 range, I decided to pick `3.4028233e+38`, which is 2nd biggest value, not counting [infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Positive_and_negative_infinity).

1. In <kbd>N</kbd> Numbers Panel go to *Group* tab.
2. Click on the *Default* color to set it. Then click on the `R` (Red) component field and paste `3.4028233e+38`
3. Make sure *Hide Value* is checked.
4. Now use the setup like below, with the value `3.4028233e+38` pasted into the *Math > Compare* node. Make sure the *Epsilon* of that node is exactly `0`:

[image]

5. <kbd>Tab</kbd> Exit to higher context, remove your custom group and add it again, to reset the value to the default_value

[image]